# I am working on POS system project using Qt GUI c++

Tags: c++, qt

For the administration menu i have few options.What i want  is when ever i trigger any menu field option one new window popup should come.To which i can use lineEdit ,labels and push button.That popup should also be connected with the database.I do not want to use designer form class because i have many field to go with.So it is not a good idea to add several designer form class.The code which i have written is.

but it gives me the error:dialog is not declared in the scope.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QDialog"
#include"qdialog.h"
#include "QLibrary"
#include "QtGui"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
   ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

  MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionChange_password_triggered()
{
```

QObject::connect(ui->actionChange_password,SIGNAL(triggered()),dialog,SLOT(show()));
     }

```
 Mr Papp here is my  mainwindow.h 
   #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
   #define MAINWINDOW_H
   #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QtDebug>
      #include <QFileInfo>
    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
  }

  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
 {
   Q_OBJECT

    public:
   explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~MainWindow();

  private slots:
  void on_actionChange_password_triggered();
    public:
   Ui::MainWindow *ui;
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Comment: In your connect function, you're using the variable dialog.  It isn't defined.  Either you need to define it, or pass the correct other value.

Comment: Can you show your mainwindow.h, too?

Comment: Mr Gabe !even if i am replacing dialog with QDialog iam getting error "In member function 'void MainWindow::on_actionChange_password_triggered()'" expected primary-expression before ',' token.IF POSSIBLE HELP ME WITH THE CODE ITSELF PLEASE.ALREADY I GOOGLED A LOT TO FIND THE SOLUTION.WITH THAT TRIGGER ACTION I WANT TO HAVE A POPUP WINDOW.That window should be use to edit password and many more action.I know to do it with designer form class,but i do not want to use designer form class.THANKS

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue here:

> QObject::connect(ui->actionChange_password,SIGNAL(triggered()),dialog,SLOT(show()));

You are having a `dialog` there. You are not having it declared in the header file of the class, most likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Mr Papp and Gabe.Actually i was trying to inherit QDialog class without declearing it.I am able to do it now.